# get mapping of list elements in a column from another dataframe column pandas

Tags: pandas

I've got two pandas DataFrames:
df1:

```
cellname        sub_str_list
    1           ['ap']
    1           ['cp','bp']
    2           ['ep','rr']
    2           ['rr', 'cp']
```

df2:

```
cellname         full_string
    1           'rec_d,rec_cp'
    1           'bp_get,dr_pet'
    1           'retap,hk_get'
    2           'tre_ep,ugt_pa'
    2           'tti_rr,par_ty'
    2           'rat_kp,cat_cp'
```

df1 has substring list whose full strings are present in df2. I need to get the full strings in df1 for corresponding sub-strings in df1(with comma separated values) .So my expected output should be :

```
cellname        sub_str_list      fulllist
    1           ['ap']            ['retap','hk_get']
    1           ['cp','bp']       ['rec_d','rec_cp','bp_get','dr_pet']
    2           ['ep','rr']       ['tre_ep','ugt_pa','tti_rr','par_ty']
    2           ['rr', 'pp']      ['tti_rr','par_ty', 'rat_kp','cat_cp']
```

Here's what I have tried.

```
res = df2.merge(df1, on='cellname', how='right').explode('sub_str_list')
res['new']=[x[1] in x[0] if x[1] is not None else False for x in zip(res['full_string'], res['sub_str_list'])]
res=res[res['new']==True]
```

Can someone help me how to proceed further, or if there's any simpler way please suggest.
Thanks in Advance!!.

Comment: Is the problem solved? Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only approach(worst) I can think of :

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
t = pd.merge(df, df2, on='cellname', how='left')
u = t.apply(lambda x: 1 if any(y in x['full_string'] for y in ast.literal_eval(x['sub_str_list'])) else 0, axis=1)
data = t[u==1].groupby(['cellname', 'sub_str_list'])[['full_string']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x['full_string'])).reset_index(name='fulllist')
```

---

**data:**

```
    cellname    sub_str_list    fulllist
0   1           ['ap']          'retap,hk_get'
1   1           ['cp','bp']     'rec_d,rec_cp','bp_get,dr_pet'
2   2           ['ep','rr']     'tre_ep,ugt_pa','tti_rr,par_ty'
3   2           ['rr', 'cp']    'tti_rr,par_ty','rat_kp,cat_cp'
```

**Edit:**

**Try:**

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
t = pd.merge(df, df1, on='cellname') #<--- merge only if there is intersection (common) not by 1st df's element.
u = t.apply(lambda x: 1 if any(y in x['nbrs'] for y in ast.literal_eval(x['nbr'])) else 0, axis=1)
data = t[u==1].groupby(['cellname', 'nbr'])[['nbrs']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x['nbrs']))#.reset_index(name='fulllist')
```

Comment: Hi @Pygirl, thanks for the solution. Sorry for the delay in reoly. But I am getting this error: ValueError: malformed node or string: ['APM1LBCH005A']

Comment: I have different strings other than that are mentioned in the question

Comment: Can you show the traceback? I guess this is due to `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: yes it is due to ast.literal_eval. I am not able to post traceback as the text is too long in comment box

Comment: i can share the links for actual df1 & df2 which I am working on.   
df1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CWv3dkVe6UET72IIWC2xXLeS0oZUiYzq/view?usp=sharing       
df2:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XnlHTd1dPjJqYZPXuGhrKuv22ILIWyM0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @anjali: I have updated my answer. If any problem occurs try to debug. I have tried to make it error free. :)

Comment: thankyou @pygirl. I am still getting same error. will solve and update after getting the solution. :)

Comment: Yes go girl :D keep on trying you will be able to solve it.